# Use properties of browserfield in http connection

Tags: blackberry

I am accessing https site(sample.aspx), To access the site we need useragent, javascript,cookie must be enabled,So i tried in browser field i am getting correct proper response,Where as in http connection i cant get the response.Please help me how to use the following properties in http connection,

```
String userAgent = "BlackBerry" + DeviceInfo.getDeviceName() + "/" +    DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion() +" Profile/" + System.getProperty("microedition.profiles") +" Configuration/" + System.getProperty( "microedition.configuration") + " VendorID/" + Branding.getVendorId()
 BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
            config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_AGENT, userAgent);
            config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ENABLE_COOKIES,Boolean.TRUE);
            config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
            myBrowserField = new BrowserField(config);
```

I need to enable javascript and cookies and in my http connection.

Answer (score 0):

you can call something like

```
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used user-agent but i dnt know how to enable javascript ?